# Is there a way that I can calculate the division of the two formulas containing a shared numbervar with grouping condition?

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, formula, crystal-reports-xi

I'm making a custom report, and there is a formulas to display the results of the division by group.

What I'm expecting is like,

| Area Manager | A/30=B | Total Age | Total DD | 

| Peter | 654.000 | 123.000 | 5.31 | 
| Peter | 653.000 | 122.000 | 5.35 | 
| Peter | 652.000 | 121.000 | 5.38 |

The report uses grouping by Area manager. so total DD is obtained from sum (A/30=b by area manager) divided by sum (age by area manager). The Age column is using subreport, the rest is in main report.

What i've got is error **"division by zero"**

And here is my formula in main report

A/30=b 
`{@Rev+Ppn}/30`

here is formula inside the subreport

```
Whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar amt_ar:= amt_ar + Sum ({@amtagetotal}, {pmproj_seed.PROJECT})
```

So, the A/30=b and subreport I put it in group footer, and I save the shared numbervar into a variable in another file.

So, I created a new file to calculate the variable, and this is how it looks like

```
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar amtdd;         // variable to display dd
numbervar a30;           // variable to display a/30=b
shared numbervar amt_ar; // variable to display Age

amtdd:=a30/amt_ar;
```

**EDIT**

So, I've tried displaying the `amt_ar` variable and I put it in to the group footer and it worked. the sum is correct based on the group. and this is the formula named gf_amt_ar

```
Whileprintingrecords;
Shared numbervar amt_ar;
```

Here's my report design looks like
[image: Here's my report design looks like]

Total AR is Total Age, and the subreport is in GF3

[image: result]
Total DD is 0,00. All I want is "the 2 blue amount" is divided and display by group in Total DD column

Comment: Have you tried isolating the divisor in your formula to validate its value?  There is only one reason you can get this error.  The `amt_ar` variable is getting a value of zero for at least one or more records.  So evaluating the value of `amt_ar` will be critical to solving this issue.

Comment: thanks for the comment @R.McMillan . do you mean evaluate to make sure the variable has a value or not? I've tried to display the amt_ar variable into the footer group and it matches the ```amt_ar``` sum based on that group. but when I use that variable to get the dd column, it's like there is no value and I don't know why.

Comment: Are there any other formulas in your report that use division?  When you click the OK button on the error message, does it open the Formula Workshop - Formula Editor window, and is it this window showing the error as occurring in this block of code, `amtdd:=a30/amt_ar;`?